# Calling a DRF View from another View

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-rest-viewsets

I have a User Model Viewset that adds users to my Django Rest Framework application (VueJS -> DRF -> PostGres).

I have another ModelViewSet for an activity log that has entries when users get credit for doing training, etc.

I ran into an issue where I realized that a user that has done nothing, skews the metrics.  To combat this, I just want to insert an Activity into the ActivityLog upon user creation.

How can I call a ModelViewSet to post a new activity from the the new user post?

I read several questions that seemed similar but I am not understanding well enough to translate to my issue.  I just want to take the ID created from the new user creation and pass that with some data to the ActivityLogViewset.

If I override perform_create() in the UserViewset, how would I call and pass the data to the other endpoint?

EDIT: OK, so I think I got tunnel vision (again).  Made it harder than it had to be.  I just overrode the perform_create, imported the ActivityLog model, and created an instance of it the way I needed.  Seems much easier than created a new request & calling the endpoint.

Thanks.

BCBB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I think I got tunnel vision (again). Made it harder than it had to be. I just overrode the perform_create, imported the ActivityLog model, and created an instance of it the way I needed. Seems much easier than created a new request & calling the endpoint.

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('last_name')
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        super().perform_create(serializer)
        user = serializer.instance
        act_cat = ActivityCategory(pk=1)
        act_desc = "You joined!"
        act = ActivityLog(user=user, activity_category=act_cat, activity_description=act_desc)
        act.save()
```